# 2010 Subaru Forester xt coolant spilled and engine keeps overheating

Tags: coolant

I bought a Subaru Forester xt recent only had it for bout a couple of days car was running great till today I had put some power on the highway and went only one exit as I got to a light I notice my hood was smoking I pulled over to notice my coolant cap open and spilled all over the engine I cleaned all the coolant and was fine for about 30 min till I saw my engine started to over heat when I pulled over I saw that there was coolant that had spilled not as much as the first time and it seemed that engine was taking a a lot of it bc it was really low after I had just filled it up the first time. Could anyone help with this. this is also my first car I and I heard that they have head gasket problems but I’m hoping that’s not the case since I only had the car for a couple of day

Comment: Welcome! After the first overheating, were you able to refill the radiator before the second time? Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

Did you purchase privately, or from a dealer? If a dealer, is there any warranty? If so, use it; get them to look at it. If you don't have a warranty, take the car to a Subaru dealer (or a Subaru Mechanic - not just any old shade-tree mechanic) and get them to give it a good checkout.

You could have a few problems; the coolant cap NEEDS to be a Subaru cap. The smoke could be from leaking valve head gaskets (relatively simple), or it could be the real head gasket issue. Check the service history to see when the head gaskets were replaced, and also to see when the timing belt was changed (every 105,000 miles). A professional viewpoint will, at this point, be invaluable for you.